# Is there a Google DFP api to check whether an ad units is active or not?

Tags: google-dfp

Is there a Google DFP api to check whether an ad unit is active or not ?

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The google publisher console can help check for active ad units, https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/2462712?hl=en.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "whether an ad unit is active or not". In general it's best to be as descriptive as posible in questions and to include what you've already tried, it saves time in the answers. I'll do my best.

If you're trying to debug whether it was properly loaded on the site, then I'd suggest you debug using the [DoubleClick Publisher Console](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/2462712?hl=en), which you can activate by adding ?googfc to the end of the URL. In there you can check which ad units are called and their status, and you can also follow the execution on the History tab inside the console.

You could also use the [Google Publisher Toolbar chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-publisher-toolbar/omioeahgfecgfpfldejlnideemfidnkc?hl=en), which has some more information on the ad being rendered, the line item, etc.

Moreover, you could set up an event listener and render information to the developer console.

```
googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {
        console.info(event);
    }
});
```

This code should be included inside the `googlgoogletag.cmd.push(function() {})` and below the slot definitions (e.g.: the method `defineSlot()`).

However, if you want to do is programatically check if an ad unit is active prior to calling it or defining it, then I think you should rephrase the question to be a bit more specific.